# get keys of self object

Tags: typescript, object

I am trying to create object with two properties and one method which do some calculation based on selected property one or property two.

Almost done, but I got error `'offset' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer.`.

What am I missing? Can you please explain to me as a beginner?

```js
const offset = { // 'offset' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer.
  start: {
    initial: 2,
    additional: additionalStartOffset
  },
  end: {
    initial: 3,
    additional: additionalEndOffset
  },
  total: function(
    this: typeof offset,
    offsetPos: keyof typeof offset // offsetPos: string | number | symbol
  ) {
    return this[offsetPos].initial + this[offsetPos].additional
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by little bit restructurizing:

```js
const offsetBasic = {
  start: {
    initial: 2,
    additional: additionalStartOffset
  },
  end: {
    initial: 3,
    additional: additionalEndOffset
  }
}

const offset = {
  ...offsetBasic,
  total: function(type: keyof typeof offsetBasic) {
    return this[type].initial + this[type].additional
  }
}
```